# fatal error: fmt/core.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, fatal-error

I am getting an error when I try to compile the following code:

> fatal error: fmt/core.h: No such file or directory

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    fmt::print("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I set up my project in VS Code and through the same application, I am setting the `c_cpp_properties.json` as follow:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/fmt"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" 
  ,
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have downloaded the fmt library with package manager MSYS2. My compiler is G++.

I tried to compile the program in any way with the `g++ hello.cpp` command.

I want to compile the program. I want to understand what I am doing wrong to not correctly include external libraries in my C++ project.

Comment: You included the wrong json. It helps to read the documentation on this. You want to include your tasks.json. Better to let cmake handle the compilation, it's just a lot easier.

Comment: ***"compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual*** That is wrong.

Comment: Did you install the fmt library properly using `pacman` in your mingw64 terminal? [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-fmt?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-fmt?repo=mingw64) The proper installation command is listed on that page: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-fmt`

Comment: To form a code block at StackOverflow 1. type ``` 2. press enter  3. paste code exactly as it is with no modification at all 4. press enter 5. type ``` 6. press enter

Comment: As `drescherjm` point out you've mixed things from `mingw` and `msvc`.